# Approximation error for numerical PDE, as l^2 norm

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, normed-spaces, finite-differences, error-propagation

I am trying to solve a Poisson equation using a second-order finite difference approximation: 
$ \frac{\partial^2 u_{i,j}}{\partial x^2} = \frac{u_{i-1,j} -2 u_{i,j} + u_{i+1,j} }{h^2} + O(h^2) $.

The equation is:

$ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{ \partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = - \pi^2 sin(\pi*x) sin(\pi*y) $,

The exact solution is: $ u = sin(\pi*x) sin(\pi*y) $.

I am trying to compute the error using an $l^2$ norm: $T = \sum_{i,j} \sqrt{ | u_{i,j}^2 - \tilde{u}_{i,j}^2 |}     $...

Qualitatively, my approximation looks great, but the error is of order$ 10^{1} $! I thought that it might just be a few spikes here and there, but when I do a surface plot of the exact solution minus the approximation, I have a nice smooth oscillating pattern with amplitude ~0.3.

Is this normal for approximating PDEs? I thought that the second order difference approximation was order 2. Shouldn't that mean that the overall error is ~$h^2$?

Thank you!

Comment: you should do $(\sum_{ij} h^2 |u_{ij} - \tilde{u}_{ij}|^2)^{1/2}$, where $\tilde{u}_{ij}$ is the reference solution at the $ij$ node

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

Why multiply by such a tiny number though? Isn't this just hiding my terrible errors!?! 

Changing the mesh size leads to a very similar number (roughly 6 or 7) in my old error norm. Doesn't this imply that there are similar differences in my approximation and in the exact solution?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So it's an average, and doesn't scale larger simply because you add more grid points. Note there are $h^{-2}$ grid points. Another interpretation is that the quantity above is a Riemann sum for an integral, and the $h^2$ is the area of each grid cell.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! 

Does this mean that we scale the error for a 1D discretization as well?

Comment: @user66081 what's the exact meaning of $h$ when using a 2D unstructured triangular mesh ?

Comment: @AmineHANINI: First, each triangle $T$ has its own $h_T$, which can be the length of the largest side or the radius of its circumcircle. If $h_T$ are all of the same order of magnitude, so $h_T \sim h$ for all $T$ (a meaningful choice is the maximal $h_T$), such a mesh is called quasi-uniform. That is the $h$.

Comment: @user66081 I got you. But can we consider it as being $h = \frac{volume(C_i)}{\sum_i volume(C_i)}$ where $C_i$ states for the current cell ?

Comment: @AmineHANINI: $\sum_i \text{vol}(C_i)$ is a constant, and $\text{vol}(C_i)$ scales as $\text{diameter}^\text{dimension}$, so the answer is *no*.  I suggest to post another question.